# Angular-dreamfactory, error 400 (Bad Request) ionic.bundle.js:18526

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, http, ionic-framework

I am using ionic in my project which about to complete, but i get strange type of response from angular-dreamfactory. On authentication process, i send http request to dsp which is in our server, for getting data from api services. All works well, even i can see the response body in chrome tool, but the function

```
  `DreamFactory.api.user.login(postData,
    function (data) {
        UserService.setUser(data);
        $scope.mediaLoading(2);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('user:loggedIn');
        $scope.loginModal.hide();
        //insert other request for data to fill app
    },
    function (errors) {
    alert("in errors");
        if (errors.error[0].code != 400) {

            $scope.mediaLoading(2);
              ... '
```

when a user enters incorrect login, it fails properly, but in second attempt in just stops responding in the app inside DreamFactory.api.user.login(postData,..) and doesnt seem to come out.
For reference:
__in 1st attempt console gives:
POST http://dsp.oshno.tj:7070/rest/user/session 400 (Bad Request) dsp.oshno.tj:7070/rest/user/session:1 // as expected
__in 2nd attempt:
http://domain_name/rest/user/session 400 (Bad Request) ionic.bundle.js:18526 // and then hangs in that function
//not expected

Please, anybody help on injecting DreamFactory properly ????

Comment: any update in this topic plz... I am stuck here... :(

Comment: in case any body had similar problem, i partially was able to solve it by using Javascript SDK instead of AngularJS,  because later i realised in git hub that AngularJS is outdated than Javascript so came up with working functionalities just by creating a .factory service to return the window.df object, 
and that works WELL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case any body had similar problem, i partially was able to solve it by using Javascript SDK instead of AngularJS, because later i realised in git hub that AngularJS is outdated than Javascript so came up with working functionalities just by creating a .factory service to return the window.df object, and that works WELL :), here [javascript sdk for DreamFactory api](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/javascript-sdk)